# The main character has white hair, can use all elements, and gets a elf witch teacher that he one shots at first meeting

Tags: story-identification, magic, isekai

The main character has white hair and is reborn into the world. His noble family does not like the fact that when they test his magic it appeared black, but that's only because he can use all elements, therefore it looked black.

Comment: Is this a manga? Manhwa? Manhua? If so, was it full colour or mostly black & white?

Answer (score 1):

Is this ***[The Only in the World, Omnipotent Wizard](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/sekai-ni-hitori-zenzokusei-mahou-no-tsukaite)***...?

> After a traffic accident, Zenichi Kiyama, a humble office worker, was reincarnated as a baby in a different world called "perfect compatibility". However, the result of his attribute appraisal with crystal was "dark attribute". The worst result is that he is a demon child...! ?

A Japanese office worker dies saving a child in a traffic accident. That child turns out to be a god who reincarnates him as the white-haired, newborn son of the noble Lakewood family in a fantasy world.

In this world, there are eight magical attributes: Earth, Water, Fire, Wind, Thunder, Ice, Dark and Light. Each person normally has one of these attributes, and it'll show up as a specific colour within a glass sphere used during an appraisal.

When the newborn protagonist is appraised, the glass sphere used turns black, which his parents interpret as meaning that he's a demon baby. They decide to pretend that he died at birth, and he winds up being adopted by his uncle and aunt, Demio and Claire Fleyfield, who name him 'Kyle' and are doting parents to him.

We then skip forward five years, and we're told that he's spent those years learning about this world and about magic, so he's now familiar with the the eight magical attributes, and can use all of them. He subsequently demonstrates to his adoptive parents that if you mix the colours of all eight attributes together, they'll show up as black within the glass spheres used for appraisals.

> [image: "The Only in the World, Omnipotent Wizard," chapter 2, page 7.]

In chapter 2, he meets an elf witch named Miluna Reizack, who's a friend of the family.

> [image: "The Only in the World, Omnipotent Wizard," chapter 2, page 11.]

She wants to see how strong his magic is, so she asks him to attack her with his full power, confident that she'll be able to block his attack, since she can use three of the eight magical attributes herself. He uses all eight attributes to hurl eight large projectiles towards her. She summons three spirits to block the attack, and manages to do so partially, but didn't expect it to be nearly as powerful as it was.